# Excel track changes by adding timestamp Not Working

Tags: excel, timestamp

[Please Check and see the sample screenshot.](http://yuvainfo.com/Excel/Excel.png)

When I update I1 Coll value, it should be update in H1 Coll time stamp But it is updating all the timestamps of H Coll.please see the Formula also.

H Col Formula is:

```
=IF(I1<>"",IF(J1="",Now(),J1),"")
```

My Doubt is when I use `NOW()`, it is automatically updating all the timestamps in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, all volatile functions update automatically whenever any cell refreshes. Now() is a volatile function. So any value you have already calculated with your formula that displays "NOW()" will update any time you enter data in a cell.

To get arround this you will either need to use a macro with VBA, or manually copy & paste values whenever you want to 'hardcode' the timestamp.